# How to get data from NSDocument's read method

Tags: swift, macos, nsdocument

I'm having difficulty trying to put 'data' onto NSPasteboard. By 'data', I mean a type other than the specific PasteboardType formats: text, HTML, image, etc. (It's actually MIDI data.)

```
override func copy() -> Any {
  let pboard = NSPasteboard.general
    pboard.clearContents()
    pboard.setData(data, forType: .typeMidi)
        return true
    }
```

When I try to put my data in, I get:

**Cannot convert value of type '(String) throws -> Data' to expected element type 'NSPasteboardWriting'.**

That's probably because I've been trying to use NSDocument's data method, but it turns out that's only for writing out to disk.

The data needs to come from the read function:

```
override func read(from data: Data, ofType typeName: String) throws {
    self.theMIDIPlayer = try AVMIDIPlayer.init(data: data, soundBankURL: nil)
    if self.theMIDIPlayer == nil {
         throw NSError(domain: NSOSStatusErrorDomain, code: unimpErr, userInfo: nil)
}
}
```

But it seems that the `read` function's arguments are not NSDocument's `data` function (which only relates to writing). I've no idea where the arguments come from.

Adding something like `self.myData = data` to the read function (in an attempt to get the data in a useful property) produce "Expected pattern" errors.

Comment: Your `data(ofType typeName: String)` function does not return anything.

Comment: @Koen It works when I use it in the read function. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: If it works somewhere else doesn't mean it is necessarily correct.

Comment: `read(from:ofType:` is related to `NSDocument`. How is the API related to your MIDI data?

Comment: @vadian Midi files are the documents of the app. This code is all in Document.swift

Comment: Then you might have an UTTypeIdentifier for the document type and can use this as the `PasteboardType`

Comment: Yes, but the pastboard type is not the problem: In the answer below, I've used "public.midi-audio" as the rawValue. The problem is actually getting the data to use in the setData method.

Comment: @vadian The problem is: how do I get the data from the read function into the copy function?

Comment: Actually you don't need to call `read(from:ofType:)` if  you have a `Data` object.

Comment: Don't I need to call `read` to load the file from disk? What would I have instead?

Comment: For example `Data(contentsOf`

Comment: So I'd need to wrap initing that object in some kind of action that gets called when I Open a document, instead of just using read?

Comment: The information that you are dealing with `NSDocument` is quite new. In the initial question you talked about `MIDI data` which seemed that the type is just raw `Data`. I will delete my answer because in a `NSDocument` environment it's wrong.

Comment: Sorry. It seemed helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: The problem was a schoolboy error of using `copy()` instead of `copy(_:)`.

Vadian's now deleted answer was helpful in creating a custom Pasteboard type.

The complete (relevant) code is as follows:

```
extension NSPasteboard.PasteboardType {
    static let typeMidi = NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(rawValue: "public.midi-audio")
}

class Document: NSDocument {

    var theMIDIPlayer: AVMIDIPlayer?
    var myData: Data?

    @IBAction func copy(_: Any)  {
      let pboard = NSPasteboard.general
        pboard.clearContents()
        pboard.setData(myData, forType: .typeMidi)
    }

    override func read(from data: Data, ofType typeName: String) throws {
        self.theMIDIPlayer = try AVMIDIPlayer.init(data: data, soundBankURL: nil)
        self.myData = data
        if self.theMIDIPlayer == nil {
             throw NSError(domain: NSOSStatusErrorDomain, code: unimpErr, userInfo: nil)
    }
    }
```